# How to create query in dart with drift orm including Expression<bool> and bool

Tags: dart

I would like to create a query in Dart using swift from table.c which is a date type.
My problem the first part is an Expression and the second is only bool
and gives the following error:

The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Expression'.

```
query.where((c) => c.date.isSmallerlValue(DateTime.now()) & (yesterday)
| (c.date.isGreaterValue(DateTime.now()) & (tomorrow));
```

I need the date of yesterdays if variable yesterday is true AND the date of tomorrows if tomorrow variable is true. (Simplified example)